# Subgroup of Isometries in Euclidean Space

Tags: group-theory, geometry

> Let $G$ be a finite subgroup of $\operatorname{Isom}(\mathbb R^n)$. By considering the barycentre (i.e. average) of the orbit of the origin unter $G$, show that $G$ fixes some point of $\mathbb R^n$. If $n=2$, show that $G$ is either cyclic or *dihedral* (that is $D_4=\mathbb Z/2\times\mathbb Z/2$, and for $n\ge3$, $D_{2n}$ is the full symmetry group of a regular $2n$-gon.)

I am struggling to show both parts. Any help will be appreciated, especially as these are the two results I am using later in other questions.

Comment: Do you have a class equation to tell you something about the average mentioned?

Comment: @EricTowers nope

Comment: Could you enhance your question with what you know about the isometries of R^n?

Comment: @EricTowers I know the types of isometries, e.g. say when n=2 there are 4 types, im sure its my groups that is letting me down here.

Comment: If you include a translation, can the resulting subgroup be finite?

Comment: Please type your question instead of pasting a screen shot. Images can't be searched, and the point of a Q&A site is that its questions can be found. You can use $\TeX$-like markup (using MathJax) for nice math notation.

Comment: @MvG thanks for that and sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Each finite group $G$ has finite orbits. Finite sets in Euclidean space have unique barycenter. Now, compute the cardinality of the $G$-orbit of the barycenter of a $G$-orbit $G\cdot x$. This computation will tell you how to find a point fixed by $G$.